# How do I add to and traverse through a LinkedList (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I can't seem to get the printing and adding to the LinkedList working as it is now.

When I add one or two nodes, it works fine. Any more than that it doesn't work as expected.

For example: adding 4 and 3 using adding first

3->4->

But when I add one more, this is what I get:

2->3->3->

Can anyone tell me with this is the case. I am fairly new to programming.

```
public class LinkedListPractice{

public static void main(String[]args){
//add items to the LinkedList
GenericLinkedList<Integer> gLink = new GenericLinkedList<>();

gLink.addFirst(4);
gLink.addFirst(3);
gLink.addFirst(2);
gLink.addFirst(1);

gLink.printList();

 }//main method

} //LinkedListPractice

class GenericLinkedList<E>{
int size; //represents number of nodes in the LinkedList
Node<E> head;

public GenericLinkedList(){
  size = 0;
  head = null;
} //GenericLinkedList no parameter constructor

//printList
public void printList(){
 Node<E> current = head;  

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
  System.out.print(current.getData() + "->");
  current = head.next;
} //for
} //printList

  public void addFirst(E element){
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);
    if(head == null){head = newNode;}  
    else{
      newNode.next = head;
      head = newNode;
   }
    size++;
  } //addFirst

  public boolean isEmpty(){
      if(head == null){
          return true;
      }else
          return false;
   } //isEmpty

  //inner node class
  private static class Node<E>{
    //private data fields
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next; //represents the next link in the LinkedList

    public Node(E element){
        data = element;
        next = null;
    } //Node class constructor

    public E getData(){
      return data;
    } //getData

  } //Node class
} //GenericLinkedList
```

Comment: `current = head.next` -> `current = current.next`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in printList(). Head never seems to get updated, so you are always printing the node after head which would be 3 in this case.

A better solution could be to update current after each iteration of a loop.